# Can't create Wordlist in Backtrack (crunch)

Tags: backtrack-linux

I am unable to create a wordlist in Backtrack by using the following command

```
./crunch 6 12 -f charset.lst mixalpha -o wordlist.txt
```

gives error

```
chunk1: fprintf failed = 28
The problem is = No space left on device
```

What could be the possible reason for failure?

Answer (score 0):

No free space left for crunch to print the entire word list

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you elaborate on your answer, it's little more than restating the problem from OP.